# Android: Make a Video transparent

Tags: android, transparency, alpha, android-videoview

i'm trying to make a video, played in a videoview transparent.
As written in the documentation the videoview should have a method "setAlpha" but my Eclipse says there is no such method?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method requires Android SDK 11 (Android 3.0 Honeycomb). So you shouldn't use this method if you want to use this app on Android 2.X devices.