# Xml hiding view

Tags: android, xml

with the xml below i am trying to show a background image while audio is playing, problem is i can't see the background image, it's covered by a black screen of the player...thanks!

Edit

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:background="#90ffffff" >

    <VideoView 
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     >
    </VideoView>


    </FrameLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The VideoView is set to fill parent. Do want to hide the VideoView and let tge User just see tge background of tge relativelayout?

Comment: Hi, I would like the user to see the background image but still see the player controls...thanks for the reply :)

Comment: can you perhaps give a screenshot. So I can understand exactly what you mean?... and no problem :) Im always glad to help

Comment: Hi, i attached a link to the screenshot, the background image is hidden behind the Videoview, i would like to be able to see the background image and still use the player controls.thanks http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/videoview.png

Comment: I have never worked with a VideoView before, but I assume you can set it transperant. Try setting it like:
android:background="#50ffffff"

Comment: hi, that shows a grey background, still covering the image

Comment: try to set it to android:background="#90ffffff" and if this still does not work. please upload a new screenshot then :)

Comment: Hi, still grey..must be another view i should use or something http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39276137/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-25%20at%206.22.08%20PM.png

Comment: Try to set your VideoView in a FrameLayout and set this framelayout to this background. This should work.

Comment: could you please show in the code? very new and would love to see what it looks like...thanks!

Comment: Posting my code as an Edit in my original question...this what u meant? same as before so far

Comment: You don't seem to be setting that _background image_ anywhere...

Comment: the background image is being setup inside an activity...it's there, just covered by the videoView

Comment: apparently the transperancy od VideoViews is just supportet by Android 3.0+. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445813/android-make-a-video-transparent